# React make variable go up randomly by a random value until it hits a threshold

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a fake loading bar kind of like Youtube when you go to a video, I want to make it last 1.5 seconds which is how much my page takes to load on avg, however this code is not working:

```
  const [fakeLoader, setFakeLoader] = useState(0);

  const startLoader = useCallback(() => {
    if (fakeLoader > 100) return;
    requestAnimationFrame(startLoader);

    if (Math.random() < 0.05) {
      setFakeLoader((prev) => (prev += Math.random() * 3));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    startLoader();
  }, [startLoader]);
```

The problem is that fakeLoader is always 0 inside the `startLoader` function so the if never runs.
I tried without the useCallback but I think that way the function changes all the time so it triggers it exponentially causing a memory leak or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've several issues in your code but the main issue is the stale enclosure of the `fakeLoader` state in the `useCallback` hook.

I would suggest using an interval to "poll" if a state update is needed. With a bit of a refactor there is this possible solution using a custom `useInterval` hook. Move the `fakeLoader < 100` into the functional state update callback so it can reference the previous state correctly.

```js
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(savedCallback.current, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
};

function App() {
  const [fakeLoader, setFakeLoader] = React.useState(0);

  const startLoader = () => {
    setFakeLoader((fakeLoader) => {
      if (fakeLoader < 100 && Math.random() < 0.05) {
        return Math.min(fakeLoader + Math.random() * 3, 100);
      }
      return fakeLoader;
    });
  };

  useInterval(startLoader, 100 / 6); // 16.666ms is approx 60fps

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(fakeLoader);
  }, [fakeLoader]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      fakeLoader: {fakeLoader.toFixed(2)}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```